# How can I make sure that someone has successfully "liked" my site when they press the "like" button on my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a rails 3 app that needs to have to a facebook "like" button and display the profile pictures of the people who have click it and complete the liking process (logging into facebook, etc). For other reasons, my app needs to know when the `@current_user` has successfully liked my site. For instance, if they click the button but they aren't logged in to facebook and never bother to log in to facebook to complete the process, my app should not think that they liked my site. What's the easiest way to do this? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a way to check people who like you through the Facebook API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach to the Facebook javascript event using FB.Event.subscribe

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // fire an ajax call to store that the user has liked you
});
```

edge.create -- fired when the user likes something (fb:like)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe