# How can I integrate Facebook's social plugin comment with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I want the owner of a post to receive an Email every time someone comments on his post. How do I get that message to Rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to my answer on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587675/how-can-i-make-sure-that-someone-has-successfully-liked-my-site-when-they-press/4587971#4587971).

Instead of attaching to the "edge.create" event, attach to the "comment.create" event

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
  // Fire an AJAX call to send an email to your post's owner
});
```