# How do I make content available on my site in exchange for a Facebook "like"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a site with a lot of for-purchase content. I also have some sampler content for "free".

A LOT of people download this sample content, and I would like to now only allow access to the free content if the user is willing to "like us" on facebook.

How can I implement this? I'm a rails developer, but it may not matter what the app is.

How can I ask a user to like us, and then verify that they have?

Comment: Here is a serverside approach, but in PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page
You should easily do this in rails too. There is no need to store the user info in your DB using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is probably where you want to start: [How can I make sure that someone has successfully "liked" my site when they press the "like" button on my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587675/how-can-i-make-sure-that-someone-has-successfully-liked-my-site-when-they-pres)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // fire an ajax call to store that the user has liked you
});
```

So then you'd handle in javascript that they have liked you, and you can unlock content to your new friends.

Comment: Won't this only capture those who've liked me via that specific button? What if they visit the fb page directly and like it there?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is using the Javascript SDK from facebook. You can read all likes from an user or ask for specific page:

```
FB.api("/me/likes/" + PAGE_ID, function(response) {
    // Do some staff here with page data
 })

FB.api("/me/likes/", function(response) {
    // Do some staff here with all pages data
 })
```

You can use the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/likes) in order to test this: